# The USB ports on my laptop stopped working, but are still active

Tags: usb

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 32-bit.

A few weeks ago, all 4 USB ports on my [Dell Latitude D620] stopped working. I can't use Flash Drives, USB keyboards, or my wifi adapter (Which means no internet, as the internal card is broken.)

However, all the ports are still active. I can boot into Kali just fine from all four, and they all work fine in kali. Plus, when I run lsub, I get:

```
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 154b:fa05 PNY
```

When my 128GB PNY flash drive is plugged in, and just a bunch of

```
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

When nothing is plugged in.

The USB ports aren't broken. How do I re-activate them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Does this also happen in the guest access?